# QColor not a registered metatype?

Tags: c++, qt

This is a follow-on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742733/qvariantlist-serialization-of-a-legacy-file) question.
That article should explain why I am using a quint16 to extract the variant type.

I have derived class MyVariant from QVariant and implemented the QDataStream read operator.

This allows constructs like:

```cpp
MyVariant vt;
str >> vt;
```

This is the streaming implementation:

```cpp
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& str, MyVariant& vt)
{
    vt.clear();

    quint16 type;
    str >> type;

    const QMetaType vtype(type);
    if (vtype.isValid()) {
        vt.create(type, nullptr);


        if (!QMetaType::load(str, type, const_cast<void *>(vt.constData()))) {
            Q_ASSERT_X(false, "MyVariant", qPrintable(QString("Cannot load type %u").arg(type)));
            str.setStatus(QDataStream::ReadCorruptData);
        }
    }
    else {
        Q_ASSERT_X(false, "MyVariant", qPrintable(QString("Type %1 is not supported").arg(type)));
    }

    return str;
}
```

When the stream comes across a QColor ([67](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)), this code fails to create a valid QMetaType for it. QMetaType::isValid() returns false.

What could I possibly have forgotten to do?

Not sure if it matters, but I have added `QT += gui` to my .pro file.

**Edit**

I have added...

```cpp
int type = qRegisterMetaType<QColor>("QColor");
```

... to my main function.
It returns 67, yet when I hit my streaming function the QMetaType creation still fails.

Comment: FTR, by the time I hit this assert, I will already have read many other types, such as QString, QStringList, QDateTime, QSizeF and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this one by pure luck.

In my main, I register the type using...

```cpp
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QColor>("QColor");
```

And now it works!
Let me know in the comments if I did the right thing or not.

Comment: `QColor` is not a `QObject`-derived type and `MyVariant` isn't `QVariant` (as much as MetaObject is concerned, that system doesn't follow polymorphic relations of non-QObjects), so yes, you have to do this.. I would say instead of  subclassing `QVariant` (for which it isn't exactly designed), you could made a wrapper around it with a conversion `operator QVariant()`.