# QVariantList serialization of a legacy file

Tags: qt

I am reading in an old legacy file format (not ours).
It's clear that this file format was written using serialization, so to make my life easier I am doing the same for reading.

At some point in reading the file, a segment is identified as being a [QMetaType::QVariantList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html).

The subsequent data reads:

```
01 00 00 00 03 00 7e 00 00 00
```

(all byte sequences in little endian)

Stepping through the deserialization into QVariantList confirms that `01 00 00 00` identifies the number of items in the list as 1.
Stepping further into the QVariant itself then shows my problem; QVariant reads the QMetaType unconditionally using a 32 bit integer

So `03 00 7e 00` becomes a QMetaType of 8257539, which is clearly wrong.

It would appear that back in the day, QVariant's meta type may have been serialized using 16 bit types, because then the data makes sense:

`03 00` becomes 3 (QMetaType::Uint)
`7e 00 00 00` becomes 126

Looking at the implementation of QVariant's serialization, there is nothing I can do via [QDataStream::setVersion()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#setVersion) either to force Qt to read the meta type as 16 bits.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do now?

Comment: It's probably not the answer you're looking for, but if you have already found and understand the current Qt code that deserializes it, you could obviously just write your own modified version.

Comment: Maybe you will need some bitwise shifts to get the proper data. Why not try shifting to align to 16 bits?